# How to check a value against each element in a vector/matrix in Python

Tags: python, loops, matrix, iteration, vectorization

It's surely pretty simple but now I have tried to get my head around this for a couple of hours.
I would like to check a value against all value in a 10x1 matrix, and if it's greater than any of them, it should be inserted before the element which is was greater than.

So far, I have tried different variation of the following code but with out luck.
What I get out, is just something like the following:

What I have tried:

```
col,col1,col2 = np.zeros((10,1)),np.zeros((10,1)),np.zeros((10,1))

for element in col:             
    if (aggdelay>element):                  
        col[n,0] = aggdelay
        col1[n,0] = flight_num
        col2[n,0] = airline_id
        break               

    n +=1
    if (n>10):
        n=0
```

The output I get looks like the following:

```
[[ 157.]
 [   3.]
 [   6.]
 [   6.]
 [   5.]
 [   9.]
 [   0.]
 [   0.]
 [   0.]
 [   0.]]
```

The input are:

```
 19790  1256    124.0
19790   1257    157.0
19790   1258    3.0
19790   1264    6.0
19790   1266    6.0
19790   1280    5.0
19790   1282    9.0
```

The expected output would be:

```
19790   1258    3.0
19790   1280    5.0
19790   1264    6.0
19790   1266    6.0
19790   1282    9.0
19790   1256    124.0
19790   1257    157.0
```

I implemented the solution provided by David, but I found it rater difficult to update the "matrix" with new elements.
This is the solution I have  at this point, but I suspect that doesn't update correctly.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import collections
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

result =np.zeros((3,1))
col,col1,col2 = []*10,[]*10,[]*10
col11,col12,col23 = [],[],[]
old_flight_num, old_airline_id = None, None

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
sumDelay1, num = 0, 1
n = 0
for line in lines:

    line, line = line.strip(), line.split("\t")

    if len(line) !=3:
        continue

    airline_id, flight_num, aggdelay = line

    try:
        aggdelay = float(aggdelay)
        flight_num= int(flight_num)
        airline_id = int(airline_id)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if (old_airline_id is not None) and (old_airline_id != airline_id):

        res2.sort(key=itemgetter(2))

        print('                                                      ')     
        print('Here come the results for airline ID: ', (old_airline_id))
        print('                                                      ')
        for row in res2:
            print(row)      

        col,col1,col2 = []*10,[]*10,[]*10

        n=0

    if (n<10):
        col.append(airline_id),col1.append(flight_num),col2.append(aggdelay)

    else:   
        res = zip(col,col1,col2)
        res.sort(key=itemgetter(2))

        if (aggdelay>min(col2)):
            res.remove(res[0])
            col11.append(airline_id), col12.append(flight_num), col23.append(aggdelay)
            res1 = zip(col11,col12,col23)
            res2=res+res1

            res2.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
    col11,col12,col23 = [],[],[]    
    n += 1

    old_airline_id = airline_id

if (old_airline_id is not None):

    res2.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
    print('                                                      ')     
    print('Here come the results for airline ID: ', (old_airline_id))
    print('                                                      ')
    for row in res2:
        print(row)
```

I would highly appreciate some guidance on this one.
Thank you!

Comment: What is a "matrix"? (There is no such data type in Python.)

Comment: Please show your code :)  Your question indicates that you have some code, but perhaps mistakenly does not actually include your code. Do you intend to insert at only the *first* instance, or at *all* instances of `val > element`?

Comment: Year, I just need to change operation system.
I hope my edit does the job David.
Please let me know if I need to explain anything in detail.
As you perhaps can see, each number in the third column has a belonging value in the first and second column.
They should also be placed at the same index as the value is stored.
I just thought that it would be easier to do it in three vectors and then combine them at the end.

Comment: @DYZ By matrix I mean a multidimensional numpy array, is this more satisfying?

Comment: have you tried the [numpy.insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) function?

Comment: how does that input map to your `agg_delay`, `flight_num` and `airline_id` variables?

Comment: Why are you starting with arrays of length 10? You'll always end up with 10 zero-values in each of those array (in addition to those you insert). It might help to show your *expected output*. Please review the [ask] section for tips to improve your question :)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the numpy.insert function, I'll try to incorporate that asap.
I read line by line and define each element of the line by airline_id, flight_num and agg_delay respectively.
I can post more of my code if you would like.
The reason why I started out with arrays of lenght 10 is because it should be an array with constant size.

Comment: If you insert, you're *increasing* the size...

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick, but I had to make some guesses as to what you expect for the output and how you're handling the input (assumed to be given in 3 columns as Airline ID, flight number, delay).

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

ids = [19790,19790,19790,19790,19790,19790,19790,19790]
flight_nums = [1256,1257,1258,1264,1266,1280,1282]
agg_delays = [124.0,157.0,3.,6.,6.,5.,9.]
m = zip(agg_delays,flight_nums,ids)  
m.sort(key=itemgetter(0),reverse=True)  # sorts the zipped list by delay, decreasing

matrix = np.array(m, np.float32)  # dumps the sorted list in to your matrix, an ndarray
```

This gives you an `ndarray` object with 3 columns, the first of which is your "delay", then the flight number, then the airline id, and it's sorted by the first column.

If you're interested in only the top-N, then just use the above to build the entire matrix and slice it:

```
# return the top 10, or however many:
matrix = matrix[:10]
```

Without using the `list.sort` method and slicing, you can sort the `ndarray` object in reverse order:

```
m = zip(agg_delays,flight_nums,ids)
matrix = np.array(m, np.float32)
matrix.sort(0)
# return the top 10, or however many:
matrix = matrix[::-1][:10]
```

Comment: Thank you for giving it try despite my  lack of information.
As I see it, your answer does the job, if I had a constant amount of information with respect to airline_id, flight_num and delay.
The case is that I have a lot more data, and the provided data just a subset of my data.
I need to evaluate each line, which contains airline_id, flight_num and delay and place it in the matrix depending on the size of the delay, such that I end up with the top 10 delay over my data with corresponding airline_id and flight_num.
I hope this clarify things a little bit more.

Comment: Use this method to build the *entire* matrix, and then just take a slice of the first 10 (or however many) items you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input David!
I'll try to incorporate it, and then I'll get back to you.

Comment: When I try to zip the three variables, I get the following error: "Zip argument #3 must support iteration"
How can I deal with this error message?
Delay is a float.

Comment: in my example I assume you collect ALL data into list or other sequence objects first.  then you can zip it.

Comment: Arh, okay! I'll try that!

Comment: David, would it be possible to control which of the variables the output is sorted by?
Right now it seems like every column is sorted and that's not working.
Other than that, it seems to do the job!

Comment: Which method are you using (`m.sort()...` or `matrix[::-1][:10]`)? I'm not sure what you mean by "every column is sorted". Perhaps you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44528243/edit) your question to include your current code. Please also include the *actual* and *expected* output so that we can see how they differ.

Comment: Hi David
I have updated my initial question, such that it include my expected output and the code I have for now.
I would need the lists containing the top 10 delays to be constant, and that's way I haven't implemented your solution completely.
As you can see from the expected output, I would like the entire "matrix" to be sorted based on the last column, the one with the actual delays in it.

Comment: What do you mean by *constant*?  What do you mean by "update the matrix"? Just process the data initially, and produce a *final* matrix only, then sort it. Without a clear problem statement and an [MCVE] including example input data (presumably with more than 10 rows of data) it's exceedingly difficult to help you. Please also show the *actual output* and explain in detail how this differs from your desired results.

Comment: It may be best if you can break this down to basic principles (i.e., do not attempt to recreate your program, simply isolate the *problem*(s) you're having and let's try to fix those). If you can't determine your actual problems, then I can't actually help you.